# How to add specific points in a GraphView Android?

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I want to add specific points on `GraphView` that look like this:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
GraphView graphView = findViewById(R.id.graph_view);
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(9);
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(9);
PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new PointsGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
        new DataPoint(-9, 9),
        new DataPoint(-9, 0),
        new DataPoint(-9, -9),
        new DataPoint(0, 9),
        new DataPoint(0, 0),
        new DataPoint(0, -9),
        new DataPoint(9, 9),
        new DataPoint(9, 0),
        new DataPoint(9, -9)
});
graphView.addSeries(series);
series.setShape(PointsGraphSeries.Shape.POINT);
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Is has nothing to do with what I want to achieve. The dots are not in the exact place like above. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the dots in the bottom images do not look like they are exactly the same as in the first  images is that you are looking at 2 different graphs :

Both of your images graphs are made out of those 2 things: 
 **x-axis** (every Horizontally point) and **y-axis**(every vertically point).

> **tl;dr** - your 2 images have different Graph scales and it is giving you the illusion of misplaced points.

**Now** - in both of your images you have the same points but the main difference is that the first graph is scaling for every Integer (both on the x-axis and y-axis) and the second graph is scaling for every second Integer(for example on x-axis -6  -4  -2  0  2  4  6).

Let's take (0, 9) point as an example - **in your first image** you can clearly see both 0 on the x-axis and 9 on the y-axis and be sure that this is your point.
**In your second image** (for the exact same point) - you can see 0 on the x-axis really clear, 9 is there too on the y-axis - you just need to notice that is it above 8 and below 10(so it is on 9 and we are talking about the same points on both images after all).

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. So how to modify the code so it can look the same as the first image?

Comment: I am not an expert regarding graph view and how to change its scale- but I can recommend you to read the documentation and check if it is mentioned in there, hope that this was helpful.

Comment: If my answer helped you out please accept it so others with the same problem could relay on it knowing that this solved your problem

Comment: Tamir, it didn't solved my issue since I still don't know what to change in order to make it work as I want.

Comment: Have a look at [this link  , it may help you](http://www.android-graphview.org/simple-graph/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188621/discussion-between-tamir-abutbul-and-johans-bormman).

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752299/how-to-reduce-the-scale-of-graphview-to-one-in-android).

Comment: Why did you open a new question for? correct me if i am wrong but you just said that  your problem is yet to solved